# CSV(ish) text handling - incorrect output on Windows, works on Linux

Tags: c, printf, fopen, fgets

I am learning C and I don't understand why this code doesn't work.

It's supposed to skip the first character, separate it in 8,4,4,4,4. But it adds one extra "0" to beginning of the second column and shifts the rest.

Also when I try to run it on Windows I can't see any results. Sometimes it can't open the file, sometimes the output is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int MAX_LINES = 10000000;

char s[1000];
int lines;
FILE *fptrIn, *fptrOut;

void convertData(char *s) {
    s[28] = 0;

    char gp1[8 + 1] = {0};
    char gp2[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp3[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp4[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp5[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp6[4 + 1] = {0};

    strncpy(gp1, s + 1, 8);
    strncpy(gp2, s + 8, 4);
    strncpy(gp3, s + 12, 4);
    strncpy(gp4, s + 16, 4);
    strncpy(gp5, s + 20, 4);
    strncpy(gp6, s + 24, 4);

    fprintf(fptrOut, "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s\n", gp1, gp2, gp3, gp4, gp5, gp6);
}

int main() {

    if ((fptrIn = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!");
        return 1;
    }

    fptrOut = fopen("testout1.txt", "w");

    fprintf(fptrOut, "Position;Sens1;Sens2;Sens3;Check;Time\n");

    while(fgets(s, sizeof s, fptrIn) != NULL) {
        lines++;
        if (strlen(s) < 28)
            continue;
        printf("Line %d#:\n", lines);
        printf("%s\n", s);
        convertData(s);
        if (lines == MAX_LINES) {
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fptrIn);
    fclose(fptrOut);

    return 0;
}
```

Input data:

```
U66ACA1000D8007670000035CBE5Cd;
U66C668000D0A07DA0000037CBF60;
U66DF84000C9908480000038CC05A(;
U66F8A0000C2A08B6000003A9C154Ä;
U67114A800BBB0923000003C9C24E„;
U6729F5000B490991000003D9C348];
```

The output using Linux:

```
Position; Sens1; Sens2; Sens3; Check; Time;
66ACA100; 00D8; 0076; 7000; 0035; CBE5;
66C66800;00D0;A07D;A000;0037;CBF6;
66DF8400;00C9;9084;8000;0038;CC05;
66F8A000;00C2;A08B;6000;003A;9C15;
67114A80;00BB;B092;3000;003C;9C24;
6729F500;00B4;9099;1000;003D;9C34;
```

And here is the whole output on Windows (although [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) is running):

```
Position;Sens1;Sens2;Sens3;Check;Time;

66ACA100;0D80;0767;0000;035C;BE5
00F3B054;8000;0039;9DDE;2‘
U;69F
27000003;A6FD;687
;U6D1;D3B8;000
3731CEEÕ;
U70;4A17;0002;3901;7A0

U73764;8000;3F20;F570;0000;340
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a few lines from the file that do not work properly along with what you expect? You should check if `fptrOut` is NULL before using it.

Comment: Please add content of your text files. At least the first few lines or if the error happens in later lines, show these lines.

Comment: If you "skip the first character", then field 1 occupies 1-8, so field 2 occupies 9-12.... Your offsets of the source string in the copying block aren't quite right...

Comment: This is used as an example in *[a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419468/why-does-the-first-line-of-a-code-block-often-get-an-extra-level-of-indentation)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any need to transfer the different fields out of `s[ ]`...

`printf()` will do what you want...

```
printf( "%8.8s,%4.4s,%4.4s,%4.4s,%4.4s,%4.4s\n",
    s + 1,
    s + 1+8,
    s + 1+8+4,
    s + 1+8+4+4,
    s + 1+8+4+4+4,
    s + 1+8+4+4+4+4
    );
```

The compiler will 'do the math', collapsing those sums into single values in the object file. Having all the numbers laid out this way in the source code makes clear the different offsets.

One other thing... If the first character of each line is 'skipped' then you want characters in positions 1 to 28... `s[28] = 0` is both wrong and unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, but now that I changed it the only result I see is the second output I posted (on windows).

Comment: The extra blank line after the header row (col titles) in your 'windows' version suggests you're having trouble with DOS/Windoze CRLF line endings being translated... Is the file corrupted? Try printing the input buffer as each line is read in...